# Непонятная структура данных

Tags: android, структуры

Изучая программирование под Андрюшу, дойдя до адаптеров наткнулся на записи подобного рода:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
    texts.length);
Map<String, Object> m;
```

Не могу понят что это, как это называется, как составлять, где и как найти по этому инфу. Предполагаю, что это как-то связано с xml. Объясните пож вкратце, как это называется, по каким запросам искать. Можно ссылки.

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Попробуйте повысить свои знания в Java с помощью книги: Брюс Эккель Философия Java. Коллекции объектов там тоже достаточно хорошо описаны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) и [Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) - это два стандартных java класса. Один - это список (формально - массив), второй - мап (то, что в других языках называют "картой" или "ассоциированным массивом").

В данном коде объявляют массив из ассоциированных массивов, ключами которых является строка, а значениями -   объект.

Почитать о этих типах можно в любой адекватной книге по java или даже на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128269/).

А вот для чего может применятся данная структрура - я не знаю.

Comment: > "ассоциированным массивом"

"ассоциативным" все же.

Comment: Спасибо! Из Ваших слов многое стало понятным. Список и ассоциированный массив встречал в разных языках. Здесь, видимо, оно используется для структурирования данных, необходимых адаптеру.

Comment: если это для адаптера, тогда очень логично. ArrayList - это типичная базовая структура для этого. Видимо в каждом элементе списка хранится по несколько именованных элементов.

@Nofate ♦  видимо автоисправление.

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>` - это всего-навсего список хэш-таблиц.

Представьте, что вы решили нескольким объектам дать текстовые имена. И записали это в таблицу. А потом несколько таких таблиц сшили в тетрадь и пронумеровали листы.

> Предполагаю, что это как-то связано с xml

Если пофантазировать на тему XML, то можно представить такую структуру - список неких "элементов" с их свойствами:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <name>Some item</name>
    <color>FFFFFF</color> 
    <size>15</size>
  </item> 
  <item>
    <name>Other item</name>
    <color>FF00FF</color> 
    <size>8</size>
  </item> 
</items>
```

Тогда внешняя коллекция `items` могла бы быть представлена как ArrayList, а хэштаблицы (`Map<String, Object>`) содержат свойства каждого отдельного item-а.

*PS. Если вы впервые видите коллекции в Java, возможно вам рановато лезть в Android.*

Comment: ооооо!!! так вот как все называется - КОЛЛЕКЦИИ. А то я ищу в своей толстой книге по Java чето подобное, типа массивы, ассоциативные массивы и все не то.... Коллекции - сразу нашел! Будем изучать. Спасибо!